# tabularray use both columns like table*?

Tags: two-column, tabularray

I can span two columns in a `twocolumn` document with `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}`.
How can I get a tabularray to span both columns?

```latex
\begin{tblr}[full-width?]{}

\end{tblr*}
```

Comment: Put `tblr` inside `table*`. You should not regard the `tblr` environment as a replacement for `table` but instead for `tabular`.

Comment: @marv Really? Does that mean I shouldn't be using the outer specification of tabularray? I thought that was the point of e.g. `caption=` and `entry=`. It's worked perfectly as a swap-in for `table` and `threeparttable` for everything except this.

Comment: the outer specification is mainly used for tables that do not float, i. e. `longtblr`. The `talltblr` environment is an exception and can be put inside a floating `table` environment. For regular `tblr` you should not use the `caption=` options and use the `\caption` command inside a `table` environment instead.

Comment: I understand your confusion but keep in mind, that `table` is just a floating container with pretty much arbitrary content that understands the `\caption` (and `\label`) commands. The `tabular` or `tblr` environment create the content and a also often referrered to as the table. However these two environments are not dependent on each other, e. g. you could place something else in `table` or use `tblr` without a surrounding `table`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Is there no way to get a `longtblr` to span two columns without starting a new page?

Comment: Should be possible with the [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=de) package. Please post a new question if you need help with that.